# Segfault when using open cv Mat::at

Tags: opencv

I am trying to fill out a opencv matrix with some values, but I keep getting segfaults. The code is following:

```
Mat mask_gx(in_window_size, in_window_size, image.type());
  for(int i = 0; i <= in_window_size; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j <= in_window_size; j++)
    {
      double gx = (-i/in_sigma) * pow(M_E, ((pow(i, 2)* pow(j, 2))/pow(in_sigma, 2))/(-2));
      mask_gx.at<double>(j, i) = gx;
    }
  }
```

The problem is in the last line. I have tested it with:

```
mask_gx.at<int>(j, i) = 1;
```

and I still get the segfault.

Does anyone have any ideas what seems to be the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `in_window_size` is the *amount* of values in each dimension, then it should be `<` and not `<=` in the `for`-loop comparisons, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it, but that doesn't solve the problem. 
Interestingly, the last line works perfectly fine outside the loop.

Comment: Could it be that `image.type()` does not correctly correspond to a type that lets you set `double` values (as in `mask_gx.at<double>`)? Maybe It corresponds to a type that is smaller than a `double`?

Comment: This problem gets more and more interesting. 
The value of in_window_size is 11. When I try putting fixed values in the loop, it works perfectly up to 7. But everything after 7 causes segfault. 
Again, the following code works perfectly fine outside the loop:
`mask_gx.at<double>(11, 11) = 1.0;`

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work for double at all, but it works for float and int only up to 7. Even if I use `mask_gx.cols` and `mask_gx.rows`, I still get segfault.

Comment: I'm really getting the feeling it has to do with the type you are using to create the `Mat` (could be wrong, I have never used this library before). Are you sure the `image.type()` is representative of `<double>` as you are trying to access it? Please see the following link for documentation regarding the `type` parameter to the `Mat` constructor: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#datatype

Comment: Thanks very much Victor. 
This solves the problem: 
` Mat mask_gx(in_window_size, in_window_size, DataType<double>::type);`