# Mat::at<double>(i,j) SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, segmentation-fault

I have been pulling my hairs on a particular code I'm maintaining, and seems not to know why the error occur.
I checked a similar error at [this location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566536/segfault-when-using-open-cv-matat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182236/the-opencv-lib-with-c-in-detail-cvmatat-causes-sigsegv-on-large-images), but suggestions offered seems not to solve my issue

Given a `Mat` image with `rows 261` and `cols 264`

```
int i = image.rows;
int j = image.cols;
int nbs[4][2] = {{i-1,j},{i,j-1},{i,j+1},{i+1,j}};

for (int n = 0; n < 4; n ++)
{
    int k = nbs[n][0];
    int l = nbs[n][1];
    renew_gI_gT(k, l);
}

void get_gT( int i, int j )
{
    // gT_x
    int d = 0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    if( i >= 0 && j - 1 > 0 && f.at<uchar>( i, j - 1 ) != INSIDE )
    {
        d += 1;
        sum += T.at<double>( i, j ) - T.at<double>( i, j - 1 );
    }
    if( i >= 0 && j + 1 < image.cols && f.at<uchar>( i, j + 1 ) != INSIDE )
    {
        d += 1;
        sum += T.at<double>( i, j + 1 ) - T.at<double>( i, j );
    }
    if( d != 0 )
    {
        sum = sum / d;
        gT_x.at<double>( i, j ) = sum;
    }

    // gT_y
    d = 0;
    sum = 0.0;
    if( i >= 0 && i - 1 > 0 && f.at<uchar>( i - 1, j ) != INSIDE )
    {
        d += 1;
        sum += T.at<double>( i, j ) - T.at<double>( i - 1, j );
    }
    if( i >= 0 && i + 1 < image.rows && f.at<uchar>( i + 1, j ) != INSIDE )
    {
        d += 1;
        sum += T.at<double>( i + 1, j ) - T.at<double>( i, j );
    }
    if( d != 0 )
    {
        sum = sum / d; 
        gT_y.at<double>( i, j ) = sum; // gdb debugger says this line causes SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. when i=261, j=249
    }
    // printf("[%d,%d] &f %f\n", i, j, gT_x.at<double>(i, j), gT_y.at<double>(i, j));
    // return;
}


void renew_gI_gT( int i, int j )
{
    get_gI( i - 1, j );
    get_gI( i, j - 1 );
    get_gI( i, j );
    get_gI( i, j + 1 );
    get_gI( i + 1, j );

    get_gT( i - 1, j );
    get_gT( i, j - 1 );
    get_gT( i, j );
    get_gT( i, j + 1 );
    get_gT( i + 1, j );

    // return;
}
```

initialization of Mat images (which are global variables) looks like so

```
T = Mat( image.rows, image.cols, CV_64FC1 );
f.create( image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1 );
gT_x = Mat( image.rows, image.cols, DataType<double>::type ); //CV_64FC1;
gT_y = Mat( image.rows, image.cols, DataType<double>::type ); //CV_64FC1;
```

The challenge is, the program works at first when a single image was used.
As soon as i loop through a set of images to use the program for each image in the set, I get the SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault at the line specified above.
Now, It won't even work for single image anymore.

I am not sure if there's a bug somewhere that my eye is not catching.

Awaiting your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix coordinates are zero-indexed, so given a `Mat` with `rows = 261`, if you call `at(i, j)` then `i` may range from 0 to 260. See the sample code at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at.